# How to insert breakpoints for knockout using chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I would like determine what value my my knockout script are returning because I have a strong feeling some of my knockout variables are returning null. I clicked on the line number then chrome is supposed to step through the code somehow please clarify the process??

thanks

Comment: insert this piece of code `debugger;`  before your problem piece and press F12 on browser and F5 alternatively you can log the data using `console.log(//your observable value)` and check console for logged value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about how to do debuggin in chrome then go through this link
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Otherwise you can retrieve the Knockout Viewmodel object in Console tab of chrome.
To use this you will have to expose the Knockout viewModel object so that you can access it from Console tab.

Otherwise just try debugging your javascript through Chrome developer tool where you are binding Knockout with your DOM

Answer (score 1):

There is Chrome Extention called "Knockoutjs context debugger",
I guess that's what you need.